# dstore add() not adding new items to data store

Tags: dojo

When I try to add a new item to the data store, it does not add it.  However it accepts the data item that I set using setData, and I am able to work with the object including get a value, observe property etc.

How do you add additional items to the data store?

My code is below.

```
<script>

    require(
        [
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dstore/Memory',
        'dmodel/extensions/jsonSchema',
        'dmodel/validators/StringValidator',
        'dmodel/store/Validating',
        "dmodel/Model",
        "dojox/json/schema",
        "dojo/text!app/model/testing/baseSchema.json",
        ], 
    function (declare, Memory, jsonSchema, StringValidator, Validating, Model, DJS, mySchema) {


        var validatingMemory2 = (declare([Memory, Validating]))({
            Model: jsonSchema(
                {
                    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                    "title": "Form Elements",
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "title": "Form Element",
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "description": "identifier",
                                "type": "string"
                            },

                            "positionX": {
                                "type": "number"
                            },

                            "positionY": {
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            "moduleType": {
                                "description": "type",
                                "type": "string"
                            }

                        },
                        "required": ["id"],
                        "additionalProperties": false
                    }
                }

                ),

            idProperty: "id",

            //additionalProperties: false //This indicates whether or not to allow additional properties outside of those defined by the schema. This defaults to true.
        });


        validatingMemory2.setData([{ "id": "one", "positionX": 100, "positionY": 200, "moduleType": "label" }]);
        console.log(validatingMemory2);

        validatingMemory2.add({ "id": "two", "positionX": 300, "positionY": 400, "moduleType": "label" }); //does not add this one

        console.log(validatingMemory2);

        var objectone = validatingMemory2.getSync("one");
        console.log(objectone.positionX); //100
        var objecttwo = validatingMemory2.getSync("two");
        console.log(objecttwo.positionX); //error undefined property

        var propOne = objectone.property("positionX");

        propOne.observe(function () {
            console.log("updated");
        });

        propOne.put(150);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dstore.add` method returns a promise and does not add immediately.

> add(object, [directives]) - This creates an object, and throws an error
>   if the object already exists. This should return a promise for the
>   newly created object.

You need to wait for the add to complete.

```
validatingMemory2.add({ "id": "two", 
                        "positionX": 300, 
                        "positionY": 400, 
                        "moduleType": "label" }).then(function(){
    var objecttwo = validatingMemory2.getSync("two");
    console.log(objecttwo.positionX);
});
```

Or use sync methods to add synchronously.

> Stores that can perform synchronous operations may provide analogous
>   methods for get, put, add, and remove that end with Sync to provide
>   synchronous support. For example getSync(id) will directly return an
>   object instead of a promise. The dstore/Memory store provides Sync
>   methods

```
validatingMemory2.addSync({ "id": "two", "positionX": 300, "positionY": 400, "moduleType": "label" });
```

Comment: What is directives?

Comment: The quote is from documentation for dstore. It is nothing but `options` or `store.PutDirectives` details can be found here https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/Store.js